# What causes the differences in price in home testing kits for lead in water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, water, analytical-chemistry

The price differences between home testing kits to test tap-water for lead are huge. 
20 dollar will either [buy 1 test](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BRSMF76) kit or [100 test strips](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0814116QB). Both are intended to test drinking-water safety.

What does this mean? Is one of the tests 100 times less sensitive? Or 100 times less accurate?
How can i as an average customer know which test is good enough?

Comment: You should shop somewhere they know what they´re selling.

Answer (score 1):

A test kit means a set of solutions for repeated use until the are spent. How many analysis can be done should be noted on the kit package.

Paper strips are easier to use, but may not be better for result.

Comment: Quantity is noted on the package: there is a package of 1 and a package of 100, both are roughly the same price. So the question is, what causes the 100 fold price difference and is this difference likely reflected in test reliability?